# Is it true that the Black Stone was given to Adam to erase his sins?

Tags: sin, kaabah

From [ancient-origins.net](http://www.ancient-origins.net/artifacts-other-artifacts/kaaba-black-stone-holy-stone-outer-space-003661):

> Muslims also believe that the Kaaba stone was once part of the stones of heaven.  There are various versions of its story of origin, all similar to one the another. When Adam was banished from the Garden of Eden, he was filled with sin. The Black Stone was given to him to erase this sin and allow him entrance back into heaven. Some instead believe the ancient stone was brought from a nearby mountain by the archangel Gabriel.

Is this true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt this was the case as the verses below indicate that how Adam was forgiven and no mention is made of the black stone in this context:

> And We said, "O Adam, dwell, you and your wife, in Paradise and eat
>   therefrom in [ease and] abundance from wherever you will. But do not
>   approach this tree, lest you be among the wrongdoers([2:35](https://quran.com/2/35))
>
> But Satan caused them to slip out of it and removed them from that
>   [condition] in which they had been. And We said, Go down, [all of
>   you], as enemies to one another, and you will have upon the earth a
>   place of settlement and provision for a time([2:36](https://quran.com/2/36))
>
> Then Adam received from his Lord [some] words, and He accepted his
>   repentance. Indeed, it is He who is the Accepting of repentance, the
>   Merciful ([2:37](https://quran.com/2/37))
>
> We said, "Go down from it, all of you. And when guidance comes to you
>   from Me, whoever follows My guidance - there will be no fear
>   concerning them, nor will they grieve([2:38](https://quran.com/2/38))

I would advice against reading articles that make statement without baking them up with evidence or how a conclusion is drawn especially when these articles are written by those who are not scholars or known to be knowledgeable in the field.

Answer (score 3):

There is a hadith with a grade of *hassan* (good) that stipulates that the black stone descended from Paradise. The hadith was documented in [Jāmi' at-Tirmidhi, Hadith 877](https://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/9/70) and [Sunan an-Nasā'i, Hadith 2935](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/1129460):

> #### عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ، أَنَّ النَّبِيَّ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ:الْحَجَرُ الأَسْوَدُ مِنَ الْجَنَّةِ
>
> It was narrated from Ibn Abbas that the Prophet said: "The Black Stone is from Paradise."
>
> <sub>— [Sunan an-Nasā'i, Hadith 2935](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/1129460)</sub>

For a matter not related to law or rulings, a *hassan* hadith can be used as proof.

Apart from the hadith by Ibn 'Abbās on the origin of the black stone, other stories are not corroborated: Gabriel bringing the black stone from a nearby mountain, or the black stone being given to Adam to erase his sins.